# Why Multiprocessing doesn't process query parallely?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want python process the query parallelly based on list of tables,

```
tables = ['TBL_A','TBL_B'
    'TBL_C','TBL_D','TBL_E',
    'TBL_F','TBL_G','TBL_H'
]
```

But apparently, it runs serially, one table to another.
It is meant the ETA 16 minutes as the largest query runs 1round 15 minutes.
FYI, I have **cpu_count = 16**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import etl_greener_01 as ego
tables = ['TBL_A','TBL_B'
    'TBL_C','TBL_D','TBL_E',
    'TBL_F','TBL_G','TBL_H'
]

lock = mp.Lock()

def task(table_nm):
    global lock

    lock.acquire()
    try:
        #print(f"Result: {table_nm.upper()}")
        print(f"Task Executed with process {mp.current_process().pid}")
        ego.extract_tbl(table_nm, ego.columns2carry(table_nm.upper(),p_kv_sy),p_kv_sy)
    finally:
        lock.release()    

def main():
  executor = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-1)
  executor.map(task, tables)
  executor.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Must running with multi process

```py
Running 'TBL_A',
Running 'TBL_B'
Running 'TBL_C'
Running 'TBL_D'
Running 'TBL_E'
Running 'TBL_F'
Running 'TBL_G'
Running 'TBL_H'
```

Comment: Why are you acquiring the lock at the very beginning of your function? Aren't locks supposed to prevent other threads from continuing execution? So you end up running one thread at a time anyway because only one thread can hold the lock at any given moment.

Comment: ^ Correct answer. This highlights the fundamental problem with multi-processing. Multiple cores are only effective when they're not blocking each other, and they do block each other when fighting over shared resources. The key to effective multi-processing therefore is the quick partitioning of inputs and the quick merger of outputs. This (and only this) should be done under a lock.

Comment: @ForceBru,
Seem your suggestion helps.

I omit `lock things`, but when I run several times, I eccountered the error below:
```python
Fail to estabilish connection to database Blank! (b'Connection error: Insufficient system resources - failed to allocate a SYSV semaphore', -832)
```